# How to transfer table from localhost server to another server in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database

I have a table with more than 1000000 rows (point,line,polygons) in localhost server and I want to transfer this table to another database in another server with PostgreSQL.

What is the best and fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

In a terminal you can use a command line like :

```
pg_dump -t "schema1"."table1" -h host1_ip -U username1 dbname1 | psql -h host2_ip -U username2 dbname2;
```

This would transfer *table1* (in *schema1*) from database *dbname1* on server *host1_ip* to *schema1* (same name) in database *dbname2* on server *host2_ip* .

Comment: This is a fast way to do it, but requires that the client's `pg_dump` version is at least as high as the server's PostgreSQL version.  It also requires that the `schema1` already exist on the destination server.  The `-1` and `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` options for `psql` are useful to prevent leaving a mess on the destination database in the event of an error.

Comment: @dd_a in SQL shell (psql), this give me an ERROR: syntax error at or near "pg_dump"

Comment: @TheoF because you must not do this from inside psql; run it from the terminal directly.

Comment: @dd_a What is the terminal? PgAdmin? (I use pgadmin). I've read elsewhere on stackexchange that it shouldn't be run from an interface like pgadmin, but from command line ie. psql.

Comment: @TheoF well, in unix systems (linux, Mac, ...) the terminal is a utility called ... 'terminal'.  I imagine you're on windows, so I guess you should run this from the command prompt in the Start menu (if you don't see it type cmd.exe), knowing that pg_dump and psql should be somewhere like C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\...  See the similar discussion here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375689/pg-dump-windows-command-prompt-invalid-command

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that are depending on PostgreSQL version and connectity.

Use the backup (for all versions, and integrated in most admin tools):

With pgdump you can export your table, send the file and reimport it to your other server. When using the dump as binary file it is the fastest option.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Use a direct connect between the databases (dblink from 9.1 upwards and postgres_fdw from 9.3):

With the dblink functions you can run a query from one server (or in many cases more important between two db) to the other. You need of course connectivity and the needed rights for it.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

As for the fastest way: As you are only in a single table with 1mio+ rows it should be really fast anyway. Otherwise i´m not sure what is faster. The manual transport is more commonly used though.